# Why does VSCode try running wsl.exe when debugging an Azure Function?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to work through the Microsoft Azure Functions tutorial [Quickstart: Create a function in Azure with Python using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python) and I'm getting stuck on the "Run the function locally" step.

When I press F5 for **Run and Debug**, I get this output in the Terminal pane:

```
 *  Executing task: .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt 

<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe .venv\Scripts\python failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return

 *  The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -e .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Why does it keep trying to run WSL, and how do I make it not do that?

The only clue on the tutorial page for fixing this error is this sentence:

> If you have trouble running on Windows, make sure that the default
> terminal for Visual Studio Code isn't set to WSL Bash.

So in VSCode, I press Sh-Ctl-P > "Terminal:Set Default Profile" > Powershell. I definitely do *not* select WSL, nor Git Bash.

This is a Windows 10 PC. My Azure Function project is in its own folder, with its own **.venv**. Although I have WSL installed, there's no reason I can think of for it to be executed in this project.The command `Get-Command python` points to the **python.exe** in the **.venv**.

I start VSCode from PowerShell, changing to the project folder and executing the command `code .` ("code space dot").

**EDITED TO ADD:** To the right of the Terminal pane is a note for "wsl task":
[image: wsl task details in terminal pane]

Comment: Have you tried modifying the following code: `"console": "internalConsole"` in `launch.json`?

Comment: Tried that. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> **Executing task: .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
>
> <3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe
> .venv\Scripts\python failed 2
>
> <3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not
> expected to return
>
> The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e
> .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt" terminated
> with exit code: 1.
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.**

I also got the above error,

[image]

**I followed the below steps to solve the error:**

Click **ctrl+shift+P** then click on **Select Default Profile** like below,

[image]

select **Azure Cloud Shell (PowerShell)** like below,

[image]

Then try running the function again by Clicking  **fn + f5**  or Click on  **run > Debug >** then **HTTP trigger** Function ran successfully like below:-

[image]

With the above **URL**, I got the output at browser as below,

[image]

Then I passed a name in the URL,

[image]

And it shows executed function successed in the terminal like below,

[image]

Comment: I followed your suggestions. I still get the same error, and it's still trying to run WSL.

Comment: @Ray Depew  Open the **Visual Studio code** terminal and select **Command prompt** option like [this](https://i.imgur.com/yF30owt.png)

Then, Try to follow below steps:
Activate the virtual environment by running the following command: **.venv\Scripts\activate**
Install the required packages by running the following command: **pip install -r requirements.txt**
Rerun the function by running the following command: **func start**